# Change the ECB menu based on content type

Tags: custom, ecb-menu

I have created Content types namely Folder content type and Document content type, the issue is when i click on the ECB menu at folder level i get an option **Edit Folder Form** but when i click on the ECB menu at Document level i get the same option **Edit Folder Form** which is not proper, i want to remove this option at Document level is it possible??

How can i change the ECB menu based on Content type?? I want that when i click on ECB menu at folder level i get Edit Folder Form option and when i click the ECB menu at Document level i should not get that option

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that by specifying a Custom Action. Sample looks something like this:

```
    <CustomAction
    Id="Test"
    Location="EditControlBlock"
    Sequence="1000"
    Title="Test Title"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
    RegistrationId="0x0120"
    Rights="ManagePermissions"
    Description="Test Description"
    >
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/TestProject/TestPage.aspx?ListID={ListId}&amp;ID=            {ItemId}"/>
    </CustomAction>
```

**UPDATE**

@Richard, Some of the properties of the current list item are present on the page. You can use them if they can meet your requirements[image]

`CAMOpt` and `CAMSep` are used to add ECB item and separator. These are OOB functions.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, how do you check item properties, and upon that display/hide the custom action?

Comment: See this http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/07/conditionally-show-menu-item-in-ecb-menu.html

Comment: Hi Nadeem, I saw this, but this checks the properties of the list itself, how do we check the properties of the item we show the ECB for? Like how do I check an item's property and upon that to display or hide the item menu? the post describes only how to check context of the list, it does not describe as well the CAMOpt and CAMSep, are these custom functions?

Comment: @Richard, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog post which shows how to conditionally show an ECB menu item. Here the condition I check is whether versioning is enabled or not. You can extend it to fix you issue.
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/07/conditionally-show-menu-item-in-ecb-menu.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the link, i have another query is it possible to call my custom form when i click on Edit properties in the ECB menu if yes can you help me with this. Do i need to write  java script or how should i proceed.